# cannot assign to property: 'CALayer' is immutable

Tags: ios, calayer, affinetransform

I'm trying to apply an affine transformation to a `CALayer` using the following code:

```
var myLayer:CALayer!
myLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)
```

But am met with the error

> cannot assign to property: 'myLayer' is immutable.

What is necessary to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to set CALayer's AffineTransform use
`myLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0))`

You can't do like this:`myLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)` because `affineTransform()` it's method, not a property

For more information, see:[CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/affineTransform)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what self is, but a UIView has a layer property, and if you wanted to grab it you could use view.layer, or set a constant (i.e. "let layer = view.layer"). Your error is most likely related to trying to coerce your immutable layer property into a var.

Comment: bat's solution solved my problem, but im interested to understand what youre talking about... wouldnt "let layer = view.layer" always be immutable tho?

Comment: Yes, using let - but your code uses "var". Actually, you could use var, but there isn't any reason to - view.layer.setA... is what you want.